# Creating layer where more attributes are presented

Tags: arcgis-10.2, arcgis-server, layers, sql-server, fields-attributes

I would like to create a layer in ArcGIS containing polylines, that are rendered by combination of more than one attribute.

I can create layer where the polylines are of different thickness or different colour. But what if I want to make combination of the attributes?

Is there a way to present a *1px red line* and another one *green 2x line*?

MSSQL data source:

```
ID | color   | thickness | geometry    
1  | 255,0,0 | 1         | polyline(...
2  | 0,255,0 | 2         | polyline(...
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for a way to set size of the symbol (line thickness) based on the attribute stored in the attribute table.

You should look for the [quantity by category](http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.2/index.html#//00s500000035000000) symbology. Here is an example of how you would set symbols.

A couple of notes:

- Line thickness field should be integer (to be used for symbol size);
- There is no way to set color of the line directly from RGB in ArcMap - you would need to pre-create a layer file by applying your RGB to a feature class by using arcpy (or manually if you don't have many unique colors).

[image]